# Draftjs: Argument of type 'htmlConverter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContentState'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

I use `convertFromHTML` from [draft-convert](https://github.com/HubSpot/draft-convert) to convert my html string to an object that can be called as parameter from `EditorState.createWithContent` from `draftjs` (as explained in the [README](https://github.com/HubSpot/draft-convert#convertfromhtml)).

But when I do something like that:

```js
const textToConvert = '<p>A paragraph</p>'
editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromHTML(textToConvert));
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I get a type definition error from TypeScript:

> Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'IConvertFromHTMLConfig'

Have I missed something because like that the WYSIWYG editor is working pretty well.

Here is the link of the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-morning-b2grr?file=/src/TextEditor.tsx)

Answer (score 4):

It must help you )

```
const textToConvert = '<p>A paragraph</p>';
const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(textToConvert);

const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
        EditorState.createWithContent(
            ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks, blocksFromHTML.entityMap)
        )
    );
```